# Simple Animation Help

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

I am just starting to try animating tikz pictures in beamer. As a test, I want to have a ball move to the right. Here is the code. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[loop]{10}
  \multiframe{10}{rPos=0.1+0.5}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [electron/.style={draw,fill,circle,shading=ball,text=white}]
    \node[electron] (e) at (\rPos,1) {$e^{-}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a common bounding box for all animation frames which encompasses all positions of the electron. Otherwise the animation's viewport moves with the electron.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{animateinline}[loop]{10}
  \multiframe{10}{rPos=0.1+0.5}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [electron/.style={draw,fill,circle,shading=ball,text=white}]
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \useasboundingbox (-0.4,0.5) rectangle (5.1,1.5);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \node[electron] (e) at (\rPos,1) {$e^{-}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```